# Accept args and put in a python list only even numbers

Tags: python, args

I have written the following Python code, but its throwing me an error

```
    def myfunc(*args):
         mylist = list()
         for num in args:
              if num%2 ==0:
              mylist = mylist.append(num)
        return mylist
```

It throws me the following error [-2, 4]!= None.

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: (1) Repair indentation of your code. (2) `list.append` returns `None`, it modifies the list in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has indent problem. It works fine if you indent it properly. like this:

```
def myfunc(x):
    mylist = list()
    for num in x:
        if num%2 ==0:
            mylist.append(num)
    return mylist
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = mylist.append(num)
```

It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate the object return `None`. `list.append` is such a function: it will add an element to the list, then return `None`. By reassignment, your `mylist` becomes `None`; which obviously then breaks in the next iteration, as `None` is not capable of being appended to.

Change the line to just

```
mylist.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(*args):
        mylist = list()
        for num in args:
                if num%2 == 0:
                        mylist.append(num)

        return mylist
```

After correcting indentation and removing assignment of `mylist` to itself - above code works.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It worked with the correct indentation as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = list()
    for num in args:
        if num%2 == 0:
            mylist.append(num)
    return mylist
```

I think it's because you are using `.append` in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = []
    for arg in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            mylist.append(arg)
    return mylist
```

make sure to call it this way

```
myfunc(-2, 4)
```